# 2 COUNTs in one SQL statement with each different conditions (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, multiple-conditions

I have been searching for a way to do this, but there is always something wrong with the help given. (It is not accepted by MYSQL, I have more conditions than the person asking question etc.)

I want to be able to count 2 things for the employees. I have 3 different conditions. How could this possibly be done ??

The COUNT code beneath is so wrong, but it is to give an idea of what I want it to do. Im outputting 2 rows so I need them to have different names.

FYI: (It works with one COUNT)

Thank you

```
SELECT employees.employees_ID,
       employees.name,
       employees.country_count_ID,
       employees.department_ID, 
       employees.initials,
       country.country_initials,

COUNT(distinct clients.retailer_ID when clients.progress_ID = 6) as aRows,
COUNT(distinct case when clients.progress_ID = 7) as bRows

FROM employees

LEFT OUTER JOIN clients ON employees.employees_ID = clients.sales_employees_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN country ON employees.country_count_ID = country.count_ID

WHERE employees.department_ID = 1

GROUP BY employees.employees_ID,
         employees.name,
         employees.country_count_ID,
         employees.department_ID,
         employees.initials,
         country.country_initials
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` with `count(distinct)`:

```
COUNT(distinct case when clients.progress_ID = 6 then clients.retailer_ID  end) as aRows,
COUNT(distinct case when clients.progress_ID = 7 then clients.retailer_ID  end) as bRows,
```